# How to read text in a file into a string variable in c

Tags: c, csv, vector

I have a csv file containing numbers separated by a commma each like `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9....`. i intend to parse all these numbers into a vector I have initialized in c programming language, I have managed to achieve the reading of all the charatcers in the file to the end of it with the code below, my problem now is assigning the characters being fetched with the `getc()` function to a string for further comma based processing where I will split the string into a string array using the comma as the separator variable. I have tried assigning the characters to the string with each iteration with no success, please help

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // define the vector file
    FILE* vec = fopen("vectors.csv", "r");
    // define the dimensions of the vector
    int rows = 100;
    // this vector has 100 rows for instance
    int vec[rows];
    //I managed to read the csv file now I need to read it into a string
    char ch,line;
    while((ch=getc(vec))!=EOF){
    //append the characters to the empty string
    line+=ch;
    }
 //confirm the accuracy of the string by outputting it
   printf("%s",line);
 //the above line outputs blank, please help
    



    return 0;
}
```

I always thought a vector was the same as a one dimension array but my research could have led me astray, please help.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `fscanf()`?  Do you have any empty fields to worry about (adjacent commas)?

Comment: No they are no empty adjacent commas. After each comma, a number exists

Comment: How do I use fscanf to do that?

Comment: So, read the numbers one at a time with `fscanf()`.  You can add a comma after the `%d`; you won't know when it is not matched, but it won't matter either.

Comment: i use a loop and then use the `fscanf()` to assign? does it return an integer?

Comment: Please read your textbook. If you don’t know how to use `fscanf()`, you need to read up on the basics.

Comment: Okay thanks for the tip, will research fscanf()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting a CSV record (a string) to an array is actually pretty easy. There are a couple of ways to do it, but using `strtok()` with a *string→int* function is perhaps the easiest.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char s[1000];
  FILE * f = fopen("vectors.csv", "r");
  while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), f))
  {
    int vector[100];
    int size = 0;

    const char * ds = " ,\t\n";  // skip spaces, commas, tabs, and that newline at the end of s[]
    for (char * token = strtok(s, ds);  token;  token = strtok(NULL, ds))
    {
      vector[size++] = atoi(token);
    }

    do_something(vector, size);
  }
  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

You may wish to add some error handling:

- `fopen()` may return NULL
- `fgets()` may not read the whole line (because there isn’t enough space in s[])
- there may be more numbers per line than space available in vectors[]
- `atoi()` may fail, but it won’t tell you if it does. `strtol()` is much better at error checking.

Notice also that your *string→int* function can be *string→whatever*: your vector could be composed of floating-point values, for example. You just need a function that will perform the conversion.

I have written it as a loop, assuming “vector*S*” means that there are multiple records in your CSV, one vector per line, and that you wish to process all of them in turn. If your file is really just a *single* vector (on a single line) then just get rid of the loop.

If your file is *massive* to the point that using three passes over the string (`fgets()` plus `strtok()` plus `atoi()` / `strtol()` / `scanf()` / whatever) becomes an issue, you can do it in a single pass with just `scanf()`. Post a comment and I’ll update the answer.

#### Update

As your file contains nothing but numbers, separated by commas, as a single vector, you can also loop using just `scanf()`.

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int vector[100];
  int size = 0;

  FILE * f = fopen("vectors.csv", "r");
  while (fscanf_s(f, "%d ,", vector + size) == 1)
  {
    size += 1;
  }
  fclose(f);

  do_something(vector, size);
}
```

While this looks very convenient, it cannot directly handle newlines in the input. If you were to wish to scan *multiple* vector records, one per line, you would still have to read the line in as a string, then parse the string. You can still do it with `sscanf()`, but it gets a tiny bit less easy to grok at first sight.

#### True single-pass parsing?

The update is a single-pass, but if you need to keep that (because you are trying to handle literally *tens of thousands* of values) *and* do it line-by-line, then you need to be a little sneakier when dealing with “delimiters”. Again, comment if it is an issue.

#### Vectors

In programming languages you can safely assume a vector some kind of list analogous to an array. The exact meaning of the term depends on either the language or the environment.

For example, vectors can be represented as tuples, arrays, lists, etc. In C++ a `vector` is a library object that represents a dynamic array. And so on.

In mathematical terms, a vector is a component of a linear space. But it is, again, often represented as a tuple of scalar values.

Comment: Why create a new vector inside the while loop for every iteration? Can you edit to initialize the vector outside te loop and then ust assign in the while loop?

Comment: The compiler is smart enough to optimize that on its own. Keeping it in the loop keeps the `vector` and `size` variables’ scope local to the loop. More importantly, the `size` of the vector needs to be initialized to zero every time through the loop, which we do with this one declaration instead of spreading it across multiple lines of code. You can, however, arrange your variables however you like.

Comment: Okay, am gonna go for the second answer because the csv files contain comma separated integers only

Comment: Yes, just remember, the second answer is too dumb to stop reading at a _single_ line of input. So if you wanted to do_something() inside the loop you would have to write a separate function to skip delimiters and recognize newlines. (It sounds like you don’t need to worry about that, though.)

Comment: where are you assigning the integers parsed in the csv to the vector?

Comment: The `fscanf()` does it. I used a bit of a different syntax than you might have expected: `vector + size` means the same thing as `&(vector[size])`. If the scan succeeds, then `size` is incremented to include the newly-appended value.

Comment: I had to change the C standard I was using in my compiler, the loop in the first solution made the compiler generate an error but I got rid of it

Answer (score 0):

Check the result of `fopen` to see if it succeeded. `if(vec == NULL) { /* error handling here */ }`.

In case there is a limited amount of numbers in the file, it will probably be easiest to read it all as one single string with `fgets`. Alternatively write a loop and call either `fgets` or `fscanf` repeatedly. In case you read the input with `fgets` you need to convert the numbers to integers with `strtol` (`fscanf` does this internally so it is easier to use).

You need to check the result of the functions to see if they succeeded, to prevent formatting errors as well as reading beyond the end of the file.

Remember to `fclose` the file handle when done.

Comment: How do i change the loop to make it assign the characters to a string and then I will split into character array and parse based on the number of rows in the vector?

Comment: @KINYUATIMOTHYNJIRU If you have it read as a string like `"1,2,3,4"` then you can actually call `strtol` repeatedly for the purpose of parsing, by using the `endptr` parameter of that function to see where it stopped reading each number.

Comment: Can you post a comprehensive answer on how I can achieve that, please?

Comment: @KINYUATIMOTHYNJIRU Sure, if you post a comprehensive question containing your code so far, including the file I/O. And not just pseudo code.

Comment: Editing to address the changes

Comment: Edited the question to make it clear what I need

Answer (score 0):

You will fail because your input (what you call a string is not string. In C there is no such thing as string but an array of chars ending with a null).

So this (the line variable in there):
char ch,line;

cannot be used like:

line+=ch;

It will just increase the char value of the "line" variable and go over and over again when it exceeds its limit (MAX_CHAR).

You better use fgets() in the first place and then malloc()/realloc()/free() memory for your char pointer by the amount of characters in each line (strlen()).
So your variable should be:
char *line;

Another solution could be to find out the count of lines in the file and then find out the maximum line length of those and then set your variable as:

char line[<max_line_length> + <line_count> + 1];

Comment: An array of characters ___is___ a string.